# Uninitialized value error with valgrind and boost::optional

Tags: c++, valgrind

I try to debug a problem where Valgrind prints uninitialized value errors when using a boost::make_optional in connection with google mock. I tried to simulate the situation with a test app usign memcmp:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>

void testFunction(  boost::optional< int > const cacheKey = boost::make_optional ( true, int() ) )
{

   boost::optional< int > const cacheKey2 = boost::make_optional ( true, int() );

   if ( memcmp ( &cacheKey, &cacheKey2, sizeof ( cacheKey2 ) ) )
   {
       printf ( "Equal\n" );
   }
}


int main(int ac, char** av)
{
   testFunction();
}


g++ -std=c++11 -g -O0 -o optionaltest optionaltest.cpp
valgrind --tool=memcheck  --track-origins=yes ./optionaltest

==16255== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==16255== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==16255== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==16255== Command: ./optionaltest
==16255== 
==16255== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==16255==    at 0x4C35D72: __memcmp_sse4_1 (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==16255==    by 0x1088F9: testFunction(boost::optional<int>) (optionaltest.cpp:11)
==16255==    by 0x108995: main (optionaltest.cpp:20)
==16255==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==16255==    at 0x1088BA: testFunction(boost::optional<int>) (optionaltest.cpp:8)
```

Is there a way to initialize the optional so that there are no uninitialized bytes inside it?

Regards

Edit: I gave both variables a make_optional now. Same error.

Edit 2: Creating a temporary std::optional, nulling it out with memset, then assigning it the value of the original and keep working with the temporary seems to work. It seems to be uninitialized memory in optional_aligned_storage.hpp. I wonder if there is a more elegant solution though.

Comment: Why not use `operator ==`?

Comment: `optional<int>` can have smaller `sizeof` than `optional<string>`. Try to check it

Comment: @Jarod42 This is not the implementation, I try to simulate what google mock does to the optional internally. Usually the parameter would go into a auto generated function by google mock with whatever happening to it, but I cannot simulate this here easily.

Comment: @fas Replacing the int by string yields the same error.

Comment: `optional` has probably padding.

Comment: `boost::optional< int >` and `boost::optional< std::string >` are two *very* different types. You can't do a byte-wise compasiron between two objects of these different types.

Comment: It doesn't matter if both objects are string or int or one of them int and one string. Same error.

Comment: I must be missing something, but the question is confusing to me. You are comparing an uninitialized object to a different object? Why are you surprised by the error?

Comment: If you look at the header of https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/boost/optional/optional.hpp, the default ctor assigns an "uninitialized object".

Comment: @Cedric I replaced the string by an int, copy/paste error. As stated before the error remains the same.

Comment: @Desperado17 From a memory point of view, yes. I guess those are two different problems.

Comment: @Cedric I gave both variables a make_optional now. Same error. Does boost_optional use default constructor?

Comment: @Desperado17 In your original example, you were explictely using a default ctor, yes. Do you still get an uninitialized error with your new version?

Comment: @Cedric yes. I did